# Make datatemplate checkbox threestates

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datatemplate

I want to make my checkbox in datatemplate has threestates I implemented a function to set datatemplate of listview columns as checkbox : but I want it to allow threestates

```
public DataTemplate SampleTemplate()
{
    DataTemplate dt = new System.Windows.DataTemplate();
    dt.DataType = typeof(bool);
    FrameworkElementFactory fef = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
    Binding bd = new Binding("EnabledThreading");
    fef.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, bd);
    dt.VisualTree = fef;
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: did you try setting the value of `IsThreeState` to true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the respective property, something along the lines of:

```
fef.SetValue(CheckBox.IsThreeStateProperty, true);
```

*([`FrameworkElementFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx) is deprecated by the way if you did not notice)*

Comment: Can I add checked and unchecked event handler to it ?

Comment: Yes, there is a method for that: [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598076.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The CheckBox has an IsChecked property which is a nullable boolean, meaning it can have three possible values - true, false, and null. Set it to the appropriate value for each instance.

You also need to set the [IsThreeState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.isthreestate%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property of the CheckBox to true.